# Celery: can I not just limit a task but do not even put in a queue if 1 is already running?

Tags: python, celery

I have this task:

```
@app.task(rate_limit='1/m')
def very_long_process():
    pass  # not very long, lol
```

and I start it from a Python function:

```
very_long_process.delay()
```

I don't want to start another one and even queue it if another instance of this task is already running.

How can I check if there is 1 running already (and get its ID)?

Answer (score 1):

```
async_result = very_long_process.delay()
task_id = async_result.id
task_status = async_result.status
task_finished = async_result.ready() # to check if task finished its execution
task_succeeded = async_result.successful() # to check if task finished its execution with success
```